# Dynamic height of two UIView's in a ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-autolayout

I have the following ViewController, with 3 UIViews and content inside. The red lines are my constraints.

[image]

The black one has always a fixed height.

The red UIView has a CollectionView inside, which will grow, depending on it's items.

The green is a UITableView which should shrink, depending on the size of the red UICollectionView.

I tried to set the height constraint of the red (UICollectionView) to greater than or equal, and the green (UITableView) height to less than or equal, but Swift is telling me to set a x or height value.

What is the correct approach to get two dynamic Views inside my ViewController?

Comment: have you tried stackView ?

Comment: I will - thank you!

Comment: yeah ... stackView with solve your issue

Comment: let me know if it doesn't solve

Comment: @ProjektWeinheim - a collection view is designed to scroll its content as you add more cells... it is not designed to expand its size. You may want to re-think that approach and use a custom view instead of a collection view.

Comment: Can you give me a direction, DonMag? I use it to show hashtags from firebase.

Comment: @ProjektWeinheim - maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60588546/6257435

Comment: Thank you Don and jawed, I used your link Don and StackView :) works!

Answer (score 0):

Create **NSLayoutConstraint** for CollectionView **Height**,Then set the height on **cellForItemAt** function

```
var collHeight:NSLayoutConstraint? //In class scope
```

Assign CollectionView height anchor to collHeight

```
collHeight = collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
collHeight!.isActive = true
```

Then set the height on **cellForItemAt** function

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        collHeight.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height
    }
```

it will expand the size of collectionview height according to item count. Next set the tableview top anchor to collectionview bottom anchor

Comment: Thank you Dilan, I got your idea and I imagine it could have worked, but used now another way to create the labels. Thank you!