# Autolayout without intrinsic size

Tags: uiview, autolayout

Can anyone tell me how Autolayout knows the size of a UIView which does not have an intrinsic size and only one dimension has been constrained?

For example, I have a plain view containing a set of subviews. The view is constrained to the leading and trailing margins of the parent and centered vertically. Autolayout is able to ask the view for its height for a given width but I don't know how. I need to layout the subviews by hand but I cannot see which function/property I need to implement so Autolayout can tell me the width and ask for the corresponding height.

Any one know?

Comment: *"I need to layout the subviews by hand"* -- do you mean in Storyboard? Or do you mean via code? In general, you either give the view a height, and have constraints layout its subviews, or... you have the constraints on the subviews determine the height of the view.

Comment: In code. I can't use Autolayout inside this view because the layout is complex. I know it would all work if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, the more complex the layout, the ***more*** reason to use auto-layout.

However, if you really want to "hand layout" your subviews and calculate the intrinsic size, you can do it by overriding `intrinsicContentSize`.

So, for example, if you *calculate* your subviews sizes / positions in `layoutSubviews()`, you should also calculate the height there, call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()`, and return your calculated height.

Here's a quick example. We add two subviews, one above the other. We give the top view a 4:1 ratio and the bottom view a 3:1 ratio.

```
class MyIntrinsicView: UIView {
    
    var myHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    let view1: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()
    let view2: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        addSubview(view1)
        addSubview(view2)
        backgroundColor = .blue
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var sz = super.intrinsicContentSize
        sz.height = myHeight
        return sz
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // let's say view 1 needs a 4:1 ratio and
        //  view 2 needs a 3:1 ratio
        view1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.width / 4.0)
        view2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view1.frame.maxY, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.width / 3.0)

        myHeight = view1.frame.height + view2.frame.height
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        
    }
    
}
```

Using this example view controller, where we give the view 60-pts leading and trailing, and only centerY constraints:

```
class QuickExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let testView = MyIntrinsicView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testView)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -60.0),
            testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

We get this output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you DonMag for a comprehensive suggestion, it's an interesting idea. It boils down to returning an initial intrinsic width of "noIntrinsicSize" and a height of zero and on  the first pass of layoutSubviews use the bounds.width to calculate the height. I will try it out.

Comment: @jspinks - if you want to look at a more "practical" example, take a look at the `TagLabelsView` class in the **Edit** part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60588546/6257435