# Display text along with border in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsattributedstring

I will get array of strings those strings need to display with border in swift iOS.

Example:

```
let tags = ["Draft", "Sent", "Inbox"]
```

The above list need to convert as a flat string and display in single line as shown in below
Expected output with border  draft image:

```
Draft Sent Inbox // All tags should have border like below also text colour should be different
```

[image]

I tried with below it works upto making single line string how to create border for each along with different colour.

```
func mergeTags(tags: [String]) -> String {
    let tagsList : String = tags.reduce("", { $0 == "" ? $1 : $0 + " " + $1 })
    return tagsList
}
```

Comment: There is nothing built one with NSAttributedString currently. You could check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners for instance, and its some work. What's the final use? Could a `UICollectionView` work (where a custom cell would have that round corner & border)? Or even a UIStackView with buttons?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60588546/6257435

Comment: Yes @DonMag but I will get max 3 strings I would like to make it without library. Can you suggest.

Comment: That answer has all the needed code -- no "libraries" used.

Comment: If it's max 3, and I guess they are "clickable", just use 3 buttons (in a UIStackView if needed), and if not clickable, 3 UILabel.