# How to make a horizontal UIStackView grow dynamically in height when content doesn't fit width?

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have a horizontal UIStackView with alignment `center` and distribution `fill`, that contains multiple UILabels. My issue is that because there are so many, they are being clipped instead of being placed on a new row.

```
(user.clubs ?? []).forEach { club in
    let emoji = club["emoji"] as? String ?? ""
    let name = club["name"] as? String ?? ""
    let typeString = club["type"] as? String ?? ""
            
    if let type = ClubType(rawValue: typeString), type == .standard {
       let label = UILabel()
                
       label.text = "\(emoji) \(name)"
       label.textColor = .black
       label.font = UIFont(name: "ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 14)
       label.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)
       label.layer.cornerRadius = 8
       label.clipsToBounds = true
                
       // ---------------------------
                
       label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                
       NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
           label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
       ])
                
       // ---------------------------
                
       clubsStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
   }
}
```

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what if you set `label. numberOfLines = 0` ?

Comment: Each label is always one line! What I want is to have the stack view's height grow dynamically base on how many labels fit on each line.

Comment: Then I am not so clear of what you want. It is a horizontal stack view which means the views will be placed in columns so why do you expect them to be placed on a new row or am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: @SotirisKaniras - a `UIStackView` has no "wrapping" capability. Your options are: use a `UICollectionView` (possibly overkill), or write code to handle the wrapping. You could do this with a stack view, or not. See this answer for one approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60588546/6257435