# Swift - UIStackView putting Objects dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistackview

I have a stack view with elements.
The elements aren't always the same.

So, to explain the whole thing:
I have cards, and each card has a tag, which means, some cards will have 0, others 1, and other 7 tags. What I wan't to do is, when I have more cards than the leadinganchor & trailing anchor can support, it puts dynamically the rest of the tags one line bottom of the first tags. Making like a list or something.

My output right now is this:

[image: Output]

If someone can help me.
I prefer not using collections, because it will make my app slow. Since this code will be repeated n times, accordingly the number of the cards.

P.S. Since this version is old, I don't use AutoLayout, all made programatically.

Thanks :)
Any question feel free to ask.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: You mean yo don't want to use UICollectionView?

Comment: You've shown us a picture of what you ***don't*** want... it will help if you also  show us a picture of what you ***do*** want. Are you trying to do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60588546/6257435

Comment: @DonMag Yes, like that, thank! I actually didn't saw it. Or its because my language isn't English, so I couldn't make myself clear. Thanks!