Showing random number of items per line
I have 15 categories that I want to show on the screen. I want to do the following

Create a box for each category so that the label fits in that box
Render as many items on the screen so that it fits. If we can render 5 items per row, do it up till we get 5 items per row
Items wrap to the next line. If we fit 5 items in one row, then the remaining items should wrap to the next line until we finish rendering all of the items.

Someone said using collection view compositional layout is the way to go. Here's what I have so far. Unfortunately, it's not rendering the categories properly. See screenshot.
import UIKit

class CategoriesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var categories = ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5", 
                      "Category 6", "Category 7", "Category 8", "Category 9", "Category 10"]
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        // Initialize collection view with a compositional layout
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CategoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Compositional Layout
    
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.2), heightDimension: .absolute(50))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        // Add spacing between items
        item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(60))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 10
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        return layout
    }
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        cell.configure(with: categories[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
}



Does this look like it could work for your task? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60588546/6257435

I have the same issue and this is how I can fix it.

First: You don’t need to create a new layout.


But remember to choose Collection View -> Size Inspector -> Estimate Size set to None.


This will let you conform to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

extension BaseViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 8
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 8
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let itemWidth = ((collectionView.bounds.width - 16)/3)
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth * 235/125)
    }
}


Second: Learn about spacing at this link: What is the difference between minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex and minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex
Third:


If you have 3 items in a row, the spacing between items is 8.
The width of each item is calculated as:
Width = (CollectionView.Width - 16) / 3.
For 5 items, the formula becomes:
Width = (CollectionView.Width - 32) / 5.


235/125 represents the ratio of your cell:

let itemWidth = ((collectionView.bounds.width - 16)/3)
return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth * 235/125)

